# eclipse paranamer plugin or something

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I currently use [paranamer.codehaus.org](http://%20paranamer.codehaus.org) to generate the functions parameter names. Everything works greate except that I need to run paranamer after every code change after eclipse builds the class. I have to manually run it. I already use the maven plugin. but it does not get invoked when eclipse builds the file.

Is there any way to tell eclipse to auto invoke  paranamer after building a class? whether using a plugin or any post building event or something? anything other than me manually invoking it everytime?

Comment: What do you mean by invoking a parameter? How do you invoke a parameter?

Comment: Is it http://paranamer.codehaus.org/ ?

Comment: Yes I mean  paranamer.codehaus.org.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean, but I guess that builders could be what you are looking for. In your eclipse project you can define builders that can run post-build. Ant for example has a builder you can use to run ant scripts.

See for example [this article](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t65486.html) or the [eclipse help](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-93_project_builder.htm)

**Edit**: Oh ok, so paranamer is a plugin, I assumed that was a typo for parameter :) 
But that makes it even easier. For each project, create an ant script that runs the paranamer, as described on the webpage. Then add a ant builder to the project that runs after each build.

Comment: I used a slightly modified approach using external programs so that I don't use ant. Thanks.